# How to send Authorization parameters to Karate Framework

Tags: authentication, karate, karate-call-single

I need to send this parameters to Karate Framework, and I don't fine how to do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMf1T.png)

Scenario: Stress ordenes en tiendas
Given path 'validation'
When method Get
Then status 200

I need some help to send this information to my request using Karate

Comment: ; please be more clear if you need to re-ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask